# Past date increased by one hour when converted to Europe/Moscow timezone

Tags: java, date, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

Could some one explain why this past date getting increased by one hour , when I convert it to Moscow Timezone ?

I'm using JDK 1.6.0_12  version.

.

```
2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300 --> Sat Apr 02 12:39:46 MSK 2011     // 11:39 --> 12:39
```

My current system time-zone is "Europe/Moscow" UTC+3 .

Also please note that this past date is in DST(Daylight Saving ) time-zone period UTC+4 , earlier used in Russia.
There was a legislative change of Russian time-zone definitions in October 2014 . Since then Russia uses UTC+3 all through out a year .

I already checked 
[this old post of 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908043/getting-incorrect-time-leading-by-1-hour-with-europe-moscow-timezone)  .

But I think this issue looks different.

Our developers expect that every past date (like "2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300" and which is in DST period ), should contain current time zone offset value i.e +0300  , not +0400 . And they think JRE is converting it incorrectly to UTC+4 , though "Default Time Zone Offset" shows +3 here . Is this way of handling time-zone offset value for past dates correct?

Same output is given on JRE 1.8 , which I think is an updated version ,there shouldn't be any issue in TZ definition in JRE 1.8.

Thanks in Advance !

Java Code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;

public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        String dateInString = "2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300";
        System.out.println(dateInString);

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
            Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        final TimeZone tzone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.println("Default Time Zone ID - " + tzone.getID());
        System.out.println("Default Time Zone Offset - (" + (tzone.getRawOffset() / 60 / 60 / 1000) + ") hour.");
    }
}
```

Output :

```
2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300
Sat Apr 02 12:39:46 MSK 2011
Default Time Zone ID - Europe/Moscow
Default Time Zone Offset - (3) hour.
```

Comment: Even with the legislative changes; they only come into effect after the date they're applied, so the change to UTC+3 should not be retroactively applied to dates prior to 2014.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, `ZoneId` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It’s a good, well considered question. You’ve explained what you found in a search and how it did not solve you issue, and you’ve provided a small and complete code example. Like very much.

Answer (score 3):

### 12:39 is the correct time

You are getting the correct result. In your string, `2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300`, the trailing `+0300` is an offset from UTC. So the point in time is the same as `2011-04-02T08:39:46+00:00` (UTC). As you say yourself, Moscow was at UTC offset +04:00 from 27 March 2011 to 26 October 2014. So to get the correct time for Moscow Java needs to add 1 hour to the hour in the string. Or 4 hours to the UTC hour of 08:39:46. In any case the time in Moscow was 12:39:46 at this point in time.

Or to answer your question:

> … why this past date getting increased by one hour , when I convert it
> to Moscow Timezone ?

Because Moscow on that date was 1 hour ahead of the time in the string.

### java.time

That said I agree with those who recommend java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for the job. `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class, and `Date` and `TimeZone` are poorly and confusingly designed too. All are long outdated. The modern API is so much nicer to work with.

For example:

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow");
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2011, 4, 2, 11, 39, 46, 0, zone); 
    System.out.println(zdt);
```

Output:

> 2011-04-02T11:39:46+04:00[Europe/Moscow]

You can also see from the output that Java knows that Moscow was at offset +04:00 back then.

Your question very well illustrates why java.time (opposite the old `TimeZone` class) makes the distinction between a time zone and an offset. A time zone includes all historic, the present and all known future offsets from UTC. This is what you need to represent historic times in Moscow correctly. In java.time a time zone is identified by a `ZoneId` object and obeys a `ZoneRules` object (most often we need not concern ourselves with the latter and can just trust Java to make the right conversions). A UTC offset is represented by a `ZoneOffset` object.

### Question: how could I use java.time with Java 1.6?

This is your lucky day. java.time exactly requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Time Changes in Moscow Over the Years](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Wow! Apart from the nice answer, the thing which I liked most is the title: `12:39 is the correct time` which set the right context.

Answer (score 0):

Both modern java date/time api and legacy one (that is used in jdk1.6) rely on system unix time and the [tzdata file](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/tzdata-versions.html) bundled with the JRE. Looks like the developers are right and your java is using a very old one version of tzdata and your developers are right.

Also, the tzdata keeps information about legal changes and if you are trying to convert date/time in the past, it will apply conversion rules that were relevant at that time.

Regarding JDK 1.8: there was an update to Russian timezone information in 8u101, so you should use at least 8u101 for a better timezone conversion.

The best decision for you would be to use modern java or update your JREs tzdata manually if you really need to use an old one.

Comment: Thanks for responding . But I compiled and executed the program with latest the JRE 8u261 .and it contains the latest tzdata . You can check this site -->https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8all-relnotes.html    . The output of the above program is same . Still there is difference of 1 hours . That's why i asked whether taking current timezone offset (+0300 ) with the past date string instead of +0400  is correct or not .

Answer (score 0):

You need to set time-zone to `SimpleDateFormat` as shown below:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String dateInString = "2011-04-02T11:39:46+0300";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Moscow"));// Set time-zone
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2011-04-02T12:39:46+0400
```

Note that `java.util.Date` does not have time-zone information. It's simply the number of milliseconds from the standard Java epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` where `Z` stands for UTC (`0` hour offset), also known as `Zulu` time-zone. At any given moment, you will get the same number of milliseconds on the JVMs sitting in any part of the word. When you try to print an object of `java.util.Date`, the date-time string for the JVM's time-zone is calculated from this milliseconds value and the same is displayed. If you want to get the date-time `String` in a specific time-zone, you need to set it explicitly to the `SimpleDateFormat` and use the same to format the `java.util.Date`.